# sidewaysfigure wrong numbering

Tags: numbering, captions, labels, rotating

I am writing a document where the second figure must be sideways.
I do this by using:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
 FIG2
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

But this changes the order of the figures. Now FIG2 comes first.

I do not know from where the problem could come. Here my header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,authoryear]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage[nooneline]{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}
\usepackage{nameref}  
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{endfloat}
```

Should I modify something by hand in the rotating package?

Comment: you don't give many clues. It is best to always make an example that reproduces the problem. sidewaystable should not alter the order. Is one of the tables a `table*` they may come out of order in older latex versions.

Comment: oh you are using endfloat. see `texdoc endfloat` section 2.4 which has something about sidewaysfloat compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`endfloat` and `sidewaystable` have some compatibility issuesm see

```
texdoc endfloat
```

section 8.2 which has some information about about `sidewaysfloat` compatibility and the need to declare `sidewaystable` to `endfloat`:

```
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}
```